# Jack and Jill bathroom locks

Tags: bathroom, lock, security

What kind of locks do I get for a jack and jill bathroom so that you can have privacy in the bathroom as well as in both bedrooms?

Comment: If someone were to go into the shared bathroom and close both doors, will they need a key to get out?

Comment: It would generally be a violation of code to have any room in a dwelling from which no exit is available without a key.

Comment: uh oh, locked inside the bathroom.

Answer (score 1):

You already answered it in your question.  You need to look for **privacy door locks**.  Also be aware that there are privacy locks that allow you to unlock from both sides (think standard bedroom lockset that gives you a small hole or allows you to use a coin to unlock from outside).  If you just have family members any standard privacy lock is fine.  If you have strangers you need to make sure the model doesn't allow the option of unlocking from other side.

Comment: OP wants both the bathroom user and bedroom user to be able to lock the door as they please.  

The only way to do that is have two doors with keyed locks like connecting hotel rooms.  Otherwise, either side can open it to get to the other side.  

For a normal friendly living situation, privacy locks with the bathroom user controlling the locks would be sufficient.  

If this was a random stranger roommate situation, I would simply use keyed door locks and just have the person in the bedroom remember to knock on the door to the bathroom before entering.

Answer (score 0):

You need a lock that can be locked from either side, if you want bedroom and bathroom privacy. The person using the room would naturally be able to exit via their own entrance, but not the other, and would be able to lock others out from both sides, while using the room. No keys should be necessary.  Everyone simply needs to remember to unlock the other door from the inside before leaving.